# Will neo4j 2 support regexp lookups via indexes?

Tags: neo4j

We have a lot of neo4j queries like the following on labeled nodes with indexes already created:

```
MATCH (entity:ARTICLE) WHERE entity.ARTICLE_ORDER_NR=~"0.*" RETURN count(DISTINCT entity);
```

Which can become slow as the database increase, which is not so weird as it doesn't use any index, looking from the profile:

```
ColumnFilter(symKeys=["  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEcd3c62e9-a90c-477a-bd5e-01741eed6ffc"], returnItemNames=["count(DISTINCT entity)"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
EagerAggregation(keys=[], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEcd3c62e9-a90c-477a-bd5e-01741eed6ffc,Distinct(Count(entity),entity))"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
  Filter(pred="LiteralRegularExpression(Property(entity,ARTICLE_ORDER_NR(221)),Literal(0.*))", _rows=19096, _db_hits=89768)
    NodeByLabel(identifier="entity", _db_hits=0, _rows=89768, label="ARTICLE", identifiers=["entity"], producer="NodeByLabel")
```

It runs through every node with the label.

Whereas the exact match uses the index we created:

```
 MATCH (entity:ARTICLE ) WHERE entity.ARTICLE_ORDER_NR="0" RETURN count(DISTINCT entity);
```

Profile:

```
ColumnFilter(symKeys=["  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEae04c897-ae93-440c-8a36-3126394ccc83"], returnItemNames=["count(DISTINCT entity)"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
EagerAggregation(keys=[], aggregates=["(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEae04c897-ae93-440c-8a36-3126394ccc83,Distinct(Count(entity),entity))"], _rows=1, _db_hits=0)
  SchemaIndex(identifier="entity", _db_hits=0, _rows=677, label="ARTICLE", query="Literal(0)", identifiers=["entity"], property="ARTICLE_ORDER_NR", producer="SchemaIndex")
```

So my guess is index lookups are not supported for regular expressions.

My question is two-fold

- Will neo4j support regexp lookups like this via index in the near
  future?
- Are there any workarounds we could use to speed this up?

Comment: I can't speak to what Neo4j 2.1 series will support, but it's worth mentioning that you can do wildcard matching with legacy lucene indexes -- this is not full regex, but can do many similar things.  If you used a lucene index on that column, it stands to reason that searching for the pattern you specify would be driven by an index, rather than scanning all nodes.   http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-lucene-extras.html

Comment: Thanks. I was already aware of them. We actually moved away from them migrating to 2.0. A bit of a bummer to find out the new indexes only work on exact matches, like that is ever useful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full-text indexing is definitely on the road map, yes. The lack of this feature is one of the few reasons the legacy indexes are not yet deprecated. The primary reason it was not part of the 2.0 release is that full-text lookups requires new cypher semantics (constructs similar to the LIKE keyword in SQL), which we want to take the time to design carefully to get right.

That said, I can't give you an estimate on when this will come, and I would advise you to use the legacy indexes for full text indexing for now.

Comment: Additional question, will it also work on matched nodes? So something like MATCH (a:A)--(b:B {some index lookup})

Comment: So, we haven't laid out the design for this properly yet, so whatever I say here is subject to me guestimating. That said, I would assume that the design we settle on will allow full text lookups to be used as a predicate in match clauses, yes. I'm not sure if we'll support full text lookups directly inside the pattern, but predicates specified in the WHERE clause are "pulled in" into the pattern at compile time, and are used to determine appropriate indexes to use for the query. This is the case currently, for exact indexes, and will be leveraged much more in the new query planner, Ronja.

Comment: Is Full-text indexing part of the 2.3 roadmap?